# Unwanted Content Is Showing in Header

Tags: magento-1.9, header

I am Working on a website, after uploading the website on the server an unwanted "print(''); " is shown in the header, i have tried to remove it but i'm unable to do that please help.

screen short is given below

[image]

Comment: Search for the word "print(''); " using grep in your app/code or app/design. Somewhere it must be lying in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get shell access

grep -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e 'print('');'